# Best practices while mutating TypeScript type object property

Tags: typescript

I have defined a type like below

```
export type SchemaDetails = {
  filename: string;
  isRoot: boolean;
  fsPath?: string;
  URIBasePath?: string;
  DBDetails?: string;
};
```

Now I have a recursive function that takes this `SchemaDetails` as an input and traverse through various nested child schemas

A typical schema looks like

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "$id": "schema_top.json",
    "allOf": [
      {
        "properties": {
          "prop1": {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "$ref": "schema_nested_1.json"
              },
              {
                "type": "object"
              }
            ]
          },
          "prop2": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "dup_file",
          "share_data"
        ]
      }
}
```

Now my type object looks like below, which I am passing to recursive function

```
const schemaData : SchemaDetails = {
    filename: "schema_top.json",
    isRoot:true,
    fsPath: "/data/artifacts/"
  }
```

And I need to change couple of `SchemaDetails` properties in every recursion , to traverse nested schemas like

```
schemaData.filename = "schema_nested_1.json"
schemaData.isRoot = false
```

Is there any other elegant way we can do this (can it be one liner) . Also if typescript allows extending an already initialised `type` object like `schemaData` to another `SchemaDetails` object .

Comment: It's unclear what solution you're looking for. If you're trying to mutate individual properties on `schemaData`, you've already written a concise way to do this. Depending on convention, I'd usually create a new object if calling recursively. if you need to preserve the three optional properties on `SchemeDetails` and only overwrite `filename` and `root`, you can construct it with `{...schemaData, filename: "schema_nested_1.json", isRoot: false}`.

Comment: Thanks @Mack this answers/explains my query